# Cufflinks and Plotly could not be imported in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

[image]

I just installed the latest version of plotly and cufflinks using pip. When I tried to import them to my Jupyter Notebook I received this error message. I am using windows and Python 3.6.2.

Comment: Did you restart your notebook? If it was already running when you installed them, then they won't be available until you restart it.